# Задача "Выборы"

Tags: c++, алгоритм

На выборах в Государственную думу в избирательные бюллетени внесено N партий. Электронный сканер для считывания информации с бюллетеней передает информацию о каждом бюллетене в следующем формате: если в соответствующей клетке бюллетеня стоит пометка, то сканер передает + (плюс), в противном случае он передает - (минус). Таким образом, он передает последовательность из N символов - плюсов и минусов.

Бюллетень считается действительным, если пометка есть ровно в одной клетке. Недействительные бюллетени в подсчете результатов выборов не участвуют.

Партия проходит в Государственную Думу, только если она набирает не менее 7% от общего числа действительных бюллетеней.

Требуется вывести номера (в порядке их перечисления в бюллетене) всех партий, которые проходят в Государственную Думу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код не проходит 1 тест, но я не знаю, какой. Помогите, пожалуйста, с задчкой.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
typedef long long ll;
using namespace std;
bool trub(string s)
{
    int kol = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        if (s[i] == '+')
            kol++;
    if (kol == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
int main()
{
    ll n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<string>a(m);
    vector<ll>b(n);
    long double kol1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        if (trub(a[i]) == true)
        {
            kol1++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        if (trub(a[i]) == true)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++)
            {
                if (a[i][j] == '+')
                    b[j]++;
            }
        }
    }
    kol1 = kol1 * 0.07;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
    {
        if (b[i] >= kol1 && b[i] != 0)
            cout << i + 1 <<' ';
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на задачу. Дайте входные данные.

Comment: Входные данные могу предоставить лишь для тех тестов, которые код проходит

Comment: Вангую, что проблема в использовании совершенно ненужной здесь арифметики с плавающей точкой. Дайте, pls, ссылку, если таковая есть - попробовать посмотреть, что там...

Comment: да, нужен нерабочий пример, будем разбираться а так.. для 4х партий 16 бюллетеней, 1 брак, получается 2 бюллетеня имеют проходной балл (1 годный бюллетень 6,67%) проверил, прошло. выиграли партии 1 и 2 ({4}
{16}
{++++}
{--+-}
{+---}
{+---}
{+---}
{+---}
{+---}
{+---}
{-+--}
{-+--}
{+---}
{+---}
{+---}
{+---}
{+---}
{+---}
{1 2})

Comment: Я бы тоже поставил на проблемы из-за округления FP, но ещё может быть перерасход памяти (если оное неразличимо с провалом теста)...